winit event loop enforces self referential struct for my wgpu state
I have been sitting at this problem for two days straight but I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve it. I'm new to rust and I lack the understanding of possible approaches.
For context: I use winit + wgpu. I start the winit event loop on my App struct. This struct is supposed to keep context over the multiple event calls. Since the window can only be created from a winit event_loop object (which is handed to me during the resume call), I need to store the created window in the App struct for later reference. However, the wgpu surface will borrow this window, and since I also need to store this wgpu state, the App struct now becomes self referential. This is the code:
use winit::{
    dpi::PhysicalSize,
    application::ApplicationHandler,
    event::*,
    event_loop::{EventLoopBuilder, EventLoopProxy, ActiveEventLoop, ControlFlow, EventLoop},
    keyboard::{KeyCode, PhysicalKey},
    window::{Window, WindowId },
};

use pollster::block_on;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum CustomEvent {
    Timer,
}

// Contains the state of the window
struct State<'w> {
    surface: wgpu::Surface<'w>,
    device: wgpu::Device,
    queue: wgpu::Queue,
    config: wgpu::SurfaceConfiguration,
    size: winit::dpi::PhysicalSize<u32>,
}


impl<'w> State<'w> {

    // This function is async because some if its operations are async
    async fn new(window: &'w Window) -> State {
        let size = window.inner_size();
        
        // Create gpu instance
        let instance_desc = wgpu::InstanceDescriptor {
            #[cfg(not(target_arch="wasm32"))]
            backends: wgpu::Backends::PRIMARY, 
            #[cfg(target_arch="wasm32")]
            backends: wgpu::Backends::GL,
            ..Default::default()
        };
        let instance = wgpu::Instance::new(instance_desc); 

        let surface = instance.create_surface(window).unwrap();

        // Could use enumerate_adapters here if we are not on WASM (there only request_adapter is available)
        let request_adapter_desc = wgpu::RequestAdapterOptions {
            power_preference: wgpu::PowerPreference::default(),
            compatible_surface: Some(&surface),
            force_fallback_adapter: false,
        };
        let adapter = instance.request_adapter(&request_adapter_desc).await.unwrap();
        
        // Create device and queue from adapter
        let device_desc = wgpu::DeviceDescriptor {
            required_features: wgpu::Features::empty(),
            required_limits: if cfg!(target_arch = "wasm32") {
                wgpu::Limits::downlevel_webgl2_defaults()
            } else {
                wgpu::Limits::default()
            },
            label: None,
            memory_hints: Default::default(),
        };
        let (device, queue) = adapter.request_device(&device_desc, None).await.unwrap(); // Set None for trace path

        // Create surface configuration
        let surface_caps = surface.get_capabilities(&adapter);

        let surface_format = surface_caps.formats.iter()
            .find(|f| f.is_srgb())
            .copied()
            .unwrap_or(surface_caps.formats[0]);
        
        let config = wgpu::SurfaceConfiguration {
            usage: wgpu::TextureUsages::RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
            format: surface_format,
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height,
            present_mode: surface_caps.present_modes[0],
            alpha_mode: surface_caps.alpha_modes[0],
            view_formats: vec![],
            desired_maximum_frame_latency: 2,
        };

        Self {
            surface,
            device,
            queue,
            config,
            size,
        }
    }

    fn resize(&mut self, size: winit::dpi::PhysicalSize<u32>) {
        if size.width > 0 && size.height > 0 {
            self.size = size;
            self.config.width = size.width;
            self.config.height = size.height;
            self.surface.configure(&self.device, &self.config); // Actually configure something
        }
    }

    fn input(&mut self, event: &WindowEvent) -> bool {
        false
    }

    fn update(&mut self) {
    }

    fn render(&mut self) -> Result<(), wgpu::SurfaceError> {
        let output = self.surface.get_current_texture()?;

        let view = output.texture.create_view(&wgpu::TextureViewDescriptor::default());

        let mut encoder = self.device.create_command_encoder(&wgpu::CommandEncoderDescriptor{
            label: Some("Render Encoder"),
        });
        
        {
            // we can store the output but it's not being used
            let _render_pass = encoder.begin_render_pass(&wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
                label: Some("Render Pass"),
                color_attachments: &[Some(wgpu::RenderPassColorAttachment {
                    view: &view,
                    resolve_target: None,
                    ops: wgpu::Operations {
                        load: wgpu::LoadOp::Clear(wgpu::Color {
                            r: 0.1,
                            g: 0.2,
                            b: 0.3,
                            a: 1.0,
                        }),
                        store: wgpu::StoreOp::Store,
                    },
                })],
                depth_stencil_attachment: None,
                occlusion_query_set: None,
                timestamp_writes: None,
            });
        }

        // submit needs an into_iter
        self.queue.submit(std::iter::once(encoder.finish()));
        output.present();

        Ok(())
    }

}

#[derive(Default)]
struct App<'w> {
    state: Option<State<'w>>,
    // Window needs to be dropped after since state contains unsafe references to it
    window: Option<Window>,
}

impl<'w> App<'w> {
}


impl<'w> ApplicationHandler<CustomEvent> for App<'w> {

    fn resumed(&mut self, event_loop: &ActiveEventLoop) {
        // Function is called on start as well
        // Create window
        self.window = Some(event_loop.create_window(Window::default_attributes()).unwrap());
        // Create a state object that we can pass through
        let state = pollster::block_on(State::new(&self.window.as_ref().unwrap()));
        self.state = Some(state);

        // self.state = Some(pollster::block_on(State::new(&self.window.as_ref().unwrap())));
    }

    fn window_event(&mut self, event_loop: &ActiveEventLoop, id: WindowId, event: WindowEvent) {
        match event {
            WindowEvent::CloseRequested => {
                println!("The close button was pressed; stopping");
                event_loop.exit();
            },
            WindowEvent::RedrawRequested => {
                // This tells winit that we want another frame after this one
                self.window.as_ref().unwrap().request_redraw();

                // Wait until we configured our surface
                if self.state.is_none() {
                    return;
                }

                self.state.as_mut().unwrap().update();

                match self.state.as_mut().unwrap().render() {
                    Ok(_) => {},
                    Err(wgpu::SurfaceError::Lost | wgpu::SurfaceError::Outdated) => {
                        let size = self.state.as_ref().unwrap().size.clone();
                        self.state.as_mut().unwrap().resize(size);
                    }
                    Err(wgpu::SurfaceError::OutOfMemory) => {
                        log::error!("Out of memory");
                        event_loop.exit();
                    }
                    // This happens when a frame takes to long to present
                    Err(wgpu::SurfaceError::Timeout) => {
                        log::warn!("Timeout");
                    }
                }
            }
            WindowEvent::KeyboardInput{ event: KeyEvent { physical_key: PhysicalKey, state: ElementState::Pressed, repeat: false, .. }, device_id, is_synthetic} => {
                println!("Goodbye see you!");
                event_loop.exit();
            }

            WindowEvent::Resized(physical_size) => {
                self.state.as_mut().unwrap().resize(physical_size);
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    }

    fn user_event(&mut self, event_loop: &ActiveEventLoop, event: CustomEvent) {
        match event {
            CustomEvent::Timer => {
                println!("Timer Event");
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    // Create Event loop
    let event_loop: EventLoop<CustomEvent> = EventLoop::with_user_event().build().unwrap();

    // Create the event loop on a seperate thread and pass events using an event loop proxy
    let event_loop_proxy: EventLoopProxy<CustomEvent> = event_loop.create_proxy();
  
    let mut app = App::default();
    event_loop.run_app(&mut app);
}

Which yields the following errors:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:170:9
    |
162 | impl<'w> ApplicationHandler<CustomEvent> for App<'w> {
    |      -- lifetime `'w` defined here
163 |
164 |     fn resumed(&mut self, event_loop: &ActiveEventLoop) {
    |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
170 |         self.state = Some(state);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'w`

And I'm honestly lost how I can avoid it. I have no control over the lifetime 'w since instance.create_surface(window) will borrow my window (or at least define the lifetime to depend on window). And also managing context for the event loop escapes my control since the only thing I can work with is this App struct that now has to keep track of window and wgpu state, so approaches like splitting the struct also don't work.
How do I tackle this?

It all makes a bit more sense when you realize that you can call instance.create_surface with an Arc<Window>, which gives you back a Surface<'static>.  All you need to do is change App like so:
#[derive(Default)]
struct App {
    state: Option<State>,
    window: Option<Arc<Window>>,
}

Note the order of the fields no longer matters, because the Window won't be dropped until both fields are, regardless of the drop order.
Then:

Remove the lifetime from State.
Remove the lifetime from all of the impl blocks for State and App.
Change State::surface to wgpu::Surface<'static>.
Change State::new() to take an Arc<Window>.
Change <State as ApplicationHandler<CustomEvent>>::resumed() to wrap the Window in an Arc, and the State::new() call to pass in a clone of the Arc.


Sorry I'm a beginner:

why does instance.create_surface create an Arc<Window> with static lifetime? Isn't the lifetime still implicitely connected to the window (or should be)?
Do I need Arc really or would Rc suffice? Why Arc specifically?


@glades create_surface doesn't create an Arc<Window>, it accepts one as argument. And since Arc<Window> is 'static (i.e. it doesn't reference anything else), then the returned Surface can be 'static too.

And you really need an Arc because WindowHandle must be Sync and Send, which Rc isn't.

BTW given your comment, you might benefit from reading Common Rust lifetime misconceptions and in particular misconception number 2 about what the 'static lifetime really means.

@glades Another way to put what is in the document Jmb linked is that if a type is 'static then it can't contain any non-'static borrows. That's it. The reason why using Arc<Window> allows the returned Surface to be 'static is because the Surface owns the Arc which in turn keeps the Window alive. There is no borrow needed here; simply holding the Arc keeps the window alive -- that's the whole point of Arc.

The approach in my answer therefore allows both the Surface and the App to "own" the same Window (though without exclusive access). Because App owns the Surface transitively through State, this means that App effectively contains two Arcs for the same Window. While this is theoretically wasteful, it allows you to decouple the lifetime of the two structs, which satisfies the borrow checker.

@cdhowie Ok thanks that makes sense! It's probably also the only approach right? Or is there any other way to avoid this heap allocation / indirection?

@glades I'm sure there's a way it can be done with unsafe code, but I doubt that's something you want to mess around with all to save a single heap allocation over the lifetime of the program, and indirection overhead that will be negligible in comparison to whatever else the program is doing.
